# Dynamically construct Preact routes from configuration - Typescript error

Tags: typescript, preact

I am testing a multi-lingual setup with different root folders for each country. There is some code-based configuration of this information that I want to reference when constructing the Preact routes.

Here's a few of the key pieces from the code:

```
import { configuration } from "./components/configuration";
import { Router, lazy } from "preact-iso";

const Home = lazy(() => import("./pages/public/Home"));

return (
   <Router>
       {
           configuration.countries.map((country) => (
               <Home path={country.rootPath} culture={country.culture} />
           ))
       }
   </Router>
):
```

This actually seems to work fine and Preact is routing the URLs correctly, but I have the following Typescript error that I don't know how to resolve:

Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'VNode<{}>': type, props, key ts(2739)

**EDIT:**
I created a simplified version of the Home page and the issue still occurs.

```
import { h, FunctionComponent } from "preact";

interface Props {
    culture: string;
};

const Home: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ culture }) => {

    return (
        <h1>Home {culture}</h1>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: What version of `preact-iso` are you using? I can't reproduce.

Comment: I am using preact-iso 2.4.0. I should also clarify that it is an error only showing up in VS Code when I open the tsx file but the app runs fine and there are no errors when I run the vite build.

Comment: Have you (for some reason) set the default export of `pages/public/Home` to return a specific type, rather than let TS infer the correct one? That's my only guess for what's going on here, what you've provided is not enough to go on.

Comment: I have edited the original question to include a simplified version of the Home page code, which still results in the TS error in VS Code. Is there anything else I can provide that would help identify what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I still can't reproduce that, you should create a Stackblitz or something. But, `FunctionComponent` annotations have been an anti-pattern for years in (p)react and should be avoided, generally you should also use `preact-iso`'s `Route` component instead of using your component directly in your router if you're a TS user (as you're adding invalid props, like `path`, to your component -- this is fine in JS, and "works" in TS, but will always create errors).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had just copied the sample code on the Preact website:

https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/typescript#function-components

What is the preferred way of defining function components now? I will also switch to using Route as you suggested.

Comment: I was reviewing the use of Route on the preact-iso repo and there are only JS examples. What is the correct way to use Route with lazy loaded components that also have props when using TS? I assume you shouldn't just add the component props directly after component={Home}, even though this does seem to work!

Comment: Just let TS infer the correct type, there's no need to explicitly set it (and explicitly setting it comes with a number of footguns, hence the suggestion to avoid it). [`Route` is built to take the component's props](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-iso/blob/9dc0bff0c6a32372ce35ebe119c9f95cbdbaa603/src/router.d.ts#L35), yes. The inverse is not true.

Comment: I have created a Stackblitz project to demonstrate the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-serjhs?file=src%2Fapp.tsx. If you remove the default route from app.tsx (under the dynamically mapped Home routes) then the TS error disappears. It only seems to be an issue when there are other adjacent routes defined.

Comment: Thanks, that is a rather important detail. Will need to play around with it more, but it very well might be a bug in `preact-iso`'s types.